# OData Core Lib - how to consume server-side paging

Tags: .net-core, odata

How to consume server-side paging using OData Core Client library?

Using the code below I'm able to fetch first page-size collection but I want to take the rest of the collection (next pages). When I'm parsing odata response I can see nextPageLink and skipToken values (so it is server-side paging). Now I want to consume the paging with OData Core Client library API. (I wasn't able to find that in its docs. Only info about how to parse the params).

```cs
var serviceRoot = "https://...";
var dataServiceContext = new GraphService(new Uri(serviceRoot));

var theCollection = await dataServiceContext.CollectionProperty.ExecuteAsync();

var countOfFristPageCollection = theCollection.Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that in lib's doc ([here link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/client/deal-with-server-driven-paging)) but with errors (they use sync versions of Execute method whilst their API offers async only - I posted that them).

This the correct code with usage of async:

```cs
var serviceRoot = "https://...";
var dataServiceContext = new MyOdataService(new Uri(serviceRoot));
DataServiceQueryContinuation<user> token = null;

var resp = (await dataServiceContext.users.ExecuteAsync()) as QueryOperationResponse<user>;

List<user> list = new List<user>();

list.AddRange(resp.ToList());

while ((token = resp.GetContinuation()) != null)
{
    resp = await dataServiceContext.ExecuteAsync<user>(token) as QueryOperationResponse<user>;

    list.AddRange(resp.ToList());
}
```